# Use a Java Class method in a Javascript function?

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, jdbc

I have a page which takes inputs and on button click adds them in a table on the same page using Javascript. It adds a new row to the table each time I add the data.
Now, I have another button which should save all the rows of table into database.

I can define a `BusinessObject` class for it and can define a method in it for all functionality of jdbc. But the question is that I can access the table element and obtain it's cells values in javascript only.

So is there a way I can access the method from my `BusinessObject` class into my javascript function?

I believe this kind of implementations is possible with AJAX. In short I want to access my Java class method into a Javascript function. Is it possible?

Comment: Let's be clear here, you *do* understand that the code is running on two different machines, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand that one runs on client and the other on server. But who knows, technology can offer many things. I didn't know if something like this exists or not. So had to confirm. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no. You'll have to create a web server in Java (probably using a framework like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or similar) which will define a URL endpoint, and that endpoint will end up using the `BusinessObject` class. On the JavaScript side, you'll just have to create the request that invokes this URL (probably via POST).